# how to make ios app keep running when terminated using core location and core bluetooth?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-location, core-bluetooth

I want to make my app function "keep running" when it terminated ( press home button 2x and swipe up the app). I'm using Core Location and Core Bluetooth.
So, the app will communicate with bluetooth low energy whenever the app is killed.

For example, I want to make it keep running like whatsapp or telegram ,etc. I mean that if we terminate the app, it keep notify user if there is new message.  I don't know whats the behavior from messaging app. Is it different from location /positioning app ?

I set local notification to know is my app running or not when terminated. Then I run the app, then i terminates it, so the app is in terminated state. the phone is locked. When i unlock the phone, there are notification from some core location function. But it not working when the screen is awake (unlocked condition)

I also already check the background modes and implement this :

```
locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization() 
manager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

Any other ideas to make my app working when it terminated?

Comment: If you want your app to keep running, don't terminate it.  You should use Bluetooth state restoration but if you kill the app from the task switcher it will  be dead.

Comment: i mean, it keep running in background when user kill the app.

Comment: If the user kills the app then it is dead

Comment: then how about whatsapp or another messaging app ? it still can receive / notify new message although it killed.  And how about maps app ?

Comment: VoiP apps can use Pushkit to receive messages when they are dead.  What about the maps app?